# Errore 1962 after replace w10 with ubuntu 15.10

Tags: grub2, 15.10, lenovo

later than 2 years I have decided to replace window disto with ubuntu 15.10 into my Lenovo C440 (I have decided to replace - no dual boot)
The installation is finished without any problems but then I could not get to work with my pc because it stops with an error - 1962.
I tried all the solutions that are in the network , enabling the legacy and forcing the boot but now, I do not know what to do . someone can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try installing a newer version of Ubuntu (16.04 now in beta) which may help with hardware and automatic EFI detection: http://distrowatch.com/?newsid=09335

Comment: -1 for suggesting to install a version of Ubuntu that is not yet relesed. For most users this will cause more problems than it will fix.